# On button click- do a redirect and ajax post submit form of new page, with data passed from click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, flask

I have a page `2.html` where if I submit an ID number, I get some output. It works with Ajax post, in which I send data along with the data parameter. At the same time, I have another page `1.html` which has a list of IDs. What I want is if I click on an ID in `1.html`, that click should pass that ID to `2.html`, submit the form on `2.html` and display that page.

The form in `2.html`:

```
$("#form").on("submit", function(event) {
  $("#results").html("");
  $.ajax({
    data: {
      name: $("#nameInput").val()
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "/similar"
  }).done(function(data) {
    /* ... */
  });
});
```

Then click in `1.html`:

```
$("#id1").on("click", function(e) {});
```

Comment: Not sure if I got it right, this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935771/how-to-ajax-post-after-a-form-submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, the best approach would be to save the value in session.
1) Using Session 
Html5 now allows storing values in session.

```
 // HTML5 session Storage
 sessionStorage.setItem("id","23");
 sessionStorage.getItem("id");
```

2) Using Cookies 
You can use jquery to set/get values from Cookies.

```
$.cookie('id', '23', {expires: 1}); // expires in 1 day
var id = $.cookie('id');
```

3) Using Query String 
The id from page 1 can be passed as GET parameter query to page2.
eg: page2.htm?id=23

```
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let param = searchParams.get('id');
```

4) Web Storage 
With HTML5 web storage, web applications can store data locally within the user's browser.
    //HTML5 local storage 
    localStorage.setItem("id","23");
    localStorage.getItem("id");

Comment: Thank you so much! I just tried the 2nd method using cookies...it worked!

Answer (score 0):

does it have to be a POST? linking to another page with some variable is better done with a GET. Are you doing it for security purposes?

```
var href= "2.html?name=" + $('#nameInput').val();
```

then digest it on 2.html... php probably?

```
$nameVal = $_GET['name'];
```

or frontend js?

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('myParam');
```

read more about frontend query string here:

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

dont forget to validate ALL input coming in ;)

Comment: Yes it worked using GET, thanks! It worked by POST too, using cookies!